# Sql Server 2008 Create Foreign Key Manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have inherited an old database which wasn't designed very well. It is a Sql Server 2008 database which is missing quite a lot of Foreign Key relationships. Below shows two of the tables, and I am trying to manually create a FK relationship between **dbo.app_status.status_id** and **dbo.app_additional_info.application_id**

[image]

I am using SQL Server Management Studio when trying to create the relationship using the query below

```
USE myDatabase; 
GO ALTER TABLE dbo.app_additional_info 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AddInfo_AppStatus FOREIGN KEY (application_id) 
    REFERENCES dbo.app_status (status_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ; 
GO
```

However, I receive this error when I run the query

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_AddInfo_AppStatus". The conflict occurred in database
>   "myDatabase", table "dbo.app_status", column 'status_id'.

I am wondering if the query is failing because each table already contains approximately 130,000 records?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I see there's a foreign key already, can you drop the existing fk first?

Comment: @Larry I am trying to add a fk to the dbo.app_additional_info table

Comment: conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AddInfo_AppStatus", and the name of FK you're trying to create is "FK_AddInfo_AppStatus", is it because of this?

Comment: I'd venture a guess that the issue is the data. There probably ar some records in the child table that do not have a matching ID in the parent table.

Try running: 

`SELECT application_id FROM app_additional_info
WHERE application_id NOT IN (SELECT status_id FROM app_status);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occuring because there is a value in `dbo.app_additional_info.application_ID` that is not in `dbo.app_Status.Status_ID`. Unless the naming convention is seriously messed up you are trying to add a relationship to unrelated columns, why would `application_ID` reference `status_ID`?

I expect that `dbo.App_Additional_Info.Application_ID` should be referencing `dbo.Application.Application_ID` (Guessing at the table and column names slightly) so you would want this:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.App_Additional_Info
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_App_Additional_Info_Application_ID (Application_ID)
    REFERENCES dbo.Application (Application_ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly the problem.